How to get rid of the additional space that I get in an environment that ends with displaymath?
I need to get rid of the additional space that I get in an environment that ends with displaymath. Consider the following MWE:
\documentclass{article}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage[]{mathtools,amsthm,amssymb,mathrsfs,mathalfa} % Math Packages
\usepackage[]{lipsum} % To get random text

% DISPLAYSKIPS

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}

% DEFINITION ENVIRONMENT

\newtheoremstyle{style4}{0pt}{0pt}{}{}{\scshape}{}{ }{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2} --- \thmnote{#3}.}
\theoremstyle{style4}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[]

% INDENTATION

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}

% DOCUMENT

\begin{document}
\begin{definition}[Property X]
    A function $f:X\to Y$ satisfies Property X if and only if
\begin{gather}
    f(x)=y
\end{gather}
\end{definition}
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}

Which gives this output, in which the space after equation (1) is larger than the space between the two paragraphs.

Q: how to get rid of the additional space that I get in an environment that ends with displaymath

What additional space? Try using equation instead of gather and you'll see. Of course, your vertical space is ruined also by the setting of \parskip.

\ignorespacesafterend removes horizontal spaces (blank characters) added unintentionally in an environment definition (for example when line breaks are not protected with %). It doesn't deal with vertical spaces.

@egreg Thank you very much for your comment. Using equation rather than gather reduces the vertical space around equation 1, but does not make the vertical space between equation 1 and the following paragraph identical to the space between the two paragraphs, which is what I’m after.

@jlab Thank you very much for your comment. Then, I have no clue how to make the vertical space after equation 1 identical to the vertical space between normal paragraphs. Any clue?

\parskip1pt
A function $f:X\to Y$ satisfies Property X if and only if...  You set parskip globally at 10pt so you need to reset it locally.

@yannisl Thank you very much for your comment. Can you please help me figure out a way to get 10pt of vertical space between text paragraphs, and identical space between equations and paragraphs that does not require me to add \parskip1pt manually every time?

it's not clear but perhaps you just want to set \abovedisplayskip and \belowdisplayskip to 0pt. Despite the title the question just seems to be about vertical space after math, not about environments or \ignorespaces

@DavidCarlisle Thank you very much for your comment. In my real document, I have already set \abovedisplayskip and \belowdisplayskip to 0. Also, I have now edited the question so that it makes sense. I think that the solution was to define `\newtheoremstyle{style4}{10pt}{0pt}{\parskip0pt}{}{\scshape}{}{ }{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2} --- \thmnote{#3}.}
\theoremstyle{style4}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[] `.

please edit the code in the question. Almost all the vertical space that you show is due to the display skips, so naturally any answer will say to set those to 0 which is a bit pointless if you say they are set to 0 already. Show an example with them set to 0 and show the spacing you get then that you want to change.

@DavidCarlisle I have now edited the question as suggested.

Thanks to the comments, I discovered that the following code solves my issue (notice the addition of \parskip0pt to the definition of the newtheoremstyle):
\documentclass{article}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage[]{mathtools,amsthm,amssymb,mathrsfs,mathalfa} % Math Packages
\usepackage[]{lipsum} % To get random text

% DISPLAYSKIPS

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}

% DEFINITION ENVIRONMENT

\newtheoremstyle{style4}{0pt}{0pt}{\parskip0pt}{}{\scshape}{}{ }{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2} --- \thmnote{#3}.}
\theoremstyle{style4}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[]

% INDENTATION

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}

% DOCUMENT

\begin{document}
\begin{definition}[Property X]
    A function $f:X\to Y$ satisfies Property X if and only if
\begin{gather}
    f(x)=y
\end{gather}
\end{definition}
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}

I am posting the solution so that the question does end up unanswered.
